# ruby loop through array and extract elements

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, extract, element

Here is what i am trying to do, but it is not working.

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]

array.each do |val1, val2, val3, val4, val5|
  puts "#{val1} topic is #{val2}, #{val3} topic is #{val4}, All topics ${val5}"
end
```

Comment: are there always 5 elements?  Will there be more?  What's the logic with the words in between?

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array.each` is going to execute the block (the part between `do` and `end`) once for every element in `array`, each time using that element as the first argument to the block.

That means the first time the block is executed, `val1` will be equal to `1`, and `val2`, `val3`, etc. will be `nil` because only one value is being passed to the block. The second time the block is executed, `val1` will be equal to `2`. `val2`, `val3`, etc. will be `nil` every time.

If you want to extract the elements of the array into variables, you don't need a loop. All you need to do is this:

```
val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 = array
puts "#{val1} topic is #{val2}, #{val3} topic is #{val4}, All topics #{val5}"
```

That's probably not necessary, though, since you can refer to the array elements directly in your string interpolation (`#{...}`):

```
puts "#{array[0]} topic is #{array[1]}, #{array[2]} topic is #{array[3]}, All topics #{array[4]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String#%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-25) method :

```
puts "%d topic is %d, %d topic is %d, All topics $%d" % array
```

Comment: I'm a fan of this method, but you should include a link to the documentation for [`sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf), since it describes the (many) formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a fixed array of elements and words between them, just do:

```
puts "#{array[0]} topic is #{array[1]}, #{array[3]} topic is #{array[4]}, All topics is #{array[5]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 = array
puts "#{val1} topic is #{val2}, #{val3} topic is #{val4}, All topics #{val5}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that allows the elements of `array` to be different types of objects, and for `array` to have a variable length (defined in a particular, suggestive way).

**Code**

```
def fmt(array)
  (array[0..-2].each_slice(2)
               .map { |e| e.join(' topic is ') } \
                << "all topics #{array.last}").join(', ')
end
```

**Examples**

```
fmt [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
  #=> "1 topic is 2, 3 topic is 4, 5 topic is 6, all topics 7"

fmt [2.1,3,"hi","ho",:a]
  #=> "2.1 topic is 3, hi topic is ho, all topics a"

array = ["First", "loops", "second", "methods", "third", "metaprogramming",
         "are important for you to understand"]

fmt(array)
  #=> "First topic is loops, second topic is methods, third topic is " +
  #   "metaprogramming, all topics are important for you to understand"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that allows the elements of `array` to be different kinds of objects and for `array` to have a variable length (defined in a particular, suggestive way).

**Code**

```
def fmt(array)
  (array[0..-2].each_slice(2)
               .map { |e| e.join(' topic is ') }
               .push "all topics #{array.last}")
               .join(', ')
end
```

**Examples**

```
fmt([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
  #=> "1 topic is 2, 3 topic is 4, 5 topic is 6, all topics 7"

fmt([1,2.5,"cat","dog",:symbol])
  #=> "1 topic is 2.5, cat topic is dog, all topics symbol"   

array = ["First", "loops", "second", "methods", "third", "metaprogramming",
         "are important for you to understand"]

fmt(array)
  #=> "First topic is loops, second topic is methods, third topic is " +
  #   "metaprogramming, all topics are important for you to understand"
```